# SQL SELECT only if a field is not empty

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT bill.bill_id, bill.bill_ref 
FROM bill
LEFT JOIN bill_item ON (bill.bill_id = bill_item.bill_id)
WHERE bill_item.job_sales_id = :job_sales_id and 
      bill.billing_type = "INV"
```

I want to add the below into my condition :

```
IF bill.bill_ref = "", 
bill.bill_ref NOT IN 
(SELECT cn_inv FROM bill a WHERE a.billing_type = "CN")
```

How should I code it?

```
bill table:  
bill_id | bill_ref | billing_type | cn_inv
--------+----------+--------------+-------
1       | INV001   | INV          |
2       |          | INV          |
3       | INV002   | INV          |
4       | CN001    | CN           | INV002
------------------------------------------
bill_item table:
bill_id | item_code | sales_id
--------+-----------+----------
1       | item001   | 10
1       | item002   | 11
2       | item001   | 13
3       | item001   | 13
4       | item001   | 13
```

when given :
sales_id is 13, return rowCount equals to 0.
sales_id is 10, return rowCount equals to 1.
sales_id is 11, return rowCount equals to 0.

Comment: Use `IS NOT NULL`

Comment: BTW the question heading and what you actually asked is two different things.

Comment: The condition in the WHERE clause `bill_item.job_sales_id =` requires that column to be non-NULL, and that negates the "outerness" of the LEFT JOIN, rendering it equivalent to an INNER join.  If you actually need an outer join, relocate the condition from the WHERE clause into the ON clause.

Comment: How you code it really depends on the specification. It's not at all clear from the question which rows should be returned, and which should not. Example data and expected output (showing examples of rows that should be returned, and rows that should be excluded) can often express the specification much more precisely. We can throw lots of possible SQL against the wall to see what sticks, but we're really just guessing at the actual specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what result is supposed to be returned.  If the specification is to *exclude* rows where there is a matching row in `bill`, we can use a `NOT EXISTS` with a correlated subquery.

If we only want the exclusion to apply when `bill_ref` is non-NULL and not an empty string ...

```
  SELECT b.bill_id
       , b.bill_ref
    FROM bill b
    JOIN bill_item i
      ON i.bill_id = b.bill_id
     AND i.job_sales_id = :job_sales_id
   WHERE b.billing_type = 'INV'
     AND b.bill_ref IS NOT NULL
     AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                        FROM bill a
                       WHERE a.cn_inv       = b.bill_ref
                         AND a.cn_inv      <> ''
                         AND a.billing_type = 'CN'
                    )
```

Note that this excludes rows that have NULL value for `bill_ref`. Query can be tweaked so that rows with NULL value of bill_ref are returned.

We could also use an anti-join pattern to return an equivalent result...

```
  SELECT b.bill_id
       , b.bill_ref
    FROM bill b
    JOIN bill_item i
      ON i.bill_id = b.bill_id
     AND i.job_sales_id = :job_sales_id
      -- anti-join exclude rows that have a match
    LEFT
    JOIN bill a
      ON a.billing_type = 'CN'
     AND a.cn_inv      <> '' 
     AND a.cn_inv       = b.bill_ref
   WHERE a.cn_inv IS NULL
     AND b.billing_type = 'INV'
     AND b.bill_ref IS NOT NULL
```

---

In the OP query, there's a condition in the WHERE clause requiring `job_sales_id` from the `bill_item` table to be non-NULL.  That condition negates the "outerness" of the LEFT join. So it's equivalent to an INNER join.

The queries in this answer preserve that behavior. (With the `LEFT` keyword removed for the join to `bill_item`, we can relocate the condition from the WHERE clause to the ON clause.)

Comment: Thanks! Yours very close to my needs! What if b.bill_ref can sometimes an empty string? I just need to make sure the b.bill_ref does not exists in column cn_inv if b.bill_ref is not null

Comment: @ShirleyKuanSF:  then just remove the `b.bill_ref IS NOT NULL` condition from the WHERE clause (in either query).  An `=` (equals compare) of a NULL value will evaluate to NULL; i.e. `foo = NULL` will never be TRUE. If you don't have a special case with the zero length string, then remove the `a.cn_inv <> ''` condition. (Providing example data example data and the expected output can help explain the specification.)

Comment: I am wating that OP confirm that this answer is correct. Nice and descriptive solution.+1. (deleted my answer)